# Que un div ocupe todo el alto si está solo

Tags: html, css, div

Como puedo hacer con CSS que un div coja el alto entero de un container si está solo, pero si está con otro div compartan el height al 50%?

Os dejo imagen que clarifica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de arriba comparten el alto del container que los contiene, al 50%, pero abajo quiero que el botón rojo ocupe todo el alto pero solo ocupa el 50%.

Código CSS

```
.time_slot_buttons_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    .time_slot_erase {
        background-color: $semantic_err_dark1;
        @include center;
        min-height: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        .time_slot_erase_img { 
            width: 25px;
        }
    }
    .time_slot_edit {
        background-color: $semantic_info_regular;
        @include center;
        min-height: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        .time_slot_edit_img {
            width: 25px;
            filter: invert(96%) sepia(34%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(81deg) brightness(103%) contrast(100%);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar así:

Cambia *min-height* por `height: calc(100%)` al ícono, o al contenedor de ícono; no al contenedor padre sino, al cual quieres que ocupe el alto total.

Si en el contenedor padre hay un hijo (el ícono), se verá 100%. Si hay más, se compartirán su altura.